# Alternate method for downloading large files

Tags: iphone, download, xcode

I want to download the iPhone SDK, but 2.7 GB is too big to download at once, so I would like to download it in parts?

Is there a link available to download the whole SDK in chunks?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Your best bet is just to download from the original link and just use a download manager that supports pause / resume.

Comment: downloads from connect.apple.com aren't resumable using Safari. I'm uncertain about other download managers

Answer (score 2):

Wil is right, your best bet is to use a download manager. The one I use is called [Leech](http://www.manytricks.com/leech/) (it's not free, but it has a trial)

Answer (score 1):

orbit ! and you are done

Answer (score 1):

Safari directly supports pause/resume download for direct download.
Otherwise, you can find maybe what you want in a torrent download.

Comment: FWIW, downloads from connect.apple.com aren't resumable using Safari. I'm uncertain about other download managers.

Answer (score 1):

maybe you could use torrents, so you can resume downloads later.